# Using methods from derived class after base class cast

Tags: class

How can I use a method of a derived class after I cast it to its derived class.

```
public class BaseClass
{
  public virtual void DoSomething()
  {
    Trace.Write("base class");
   }
}

public class DerivedClass : BaseClass
{
  public override void DoSomethingElse()
  {
    Trace.Write("derived class");
  }
}
```

I want to be able to call

```
BaseClass B ( (BaseClass*) new DerivedClass());
B.DoSomethingElse();
```

I need B cast as BaseClass for different reasons...Could I have a instant of the derived class called C, then cast it as the BaseClass and have two different references to the same instant?

Comment: This is not C++ code

Comment: Didn't realize I was mixing c# code in here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're using C#, but the idea is the same regardless. You have to cast the object to the type in which the desired method exists. Consider (the following is C++):

```
BaseClass* b = new DerivedClass( );
b->DoSomethingElse( ); // fails because this method doesn't exist for BaseClass
((DerivedClass*)b)->DoSomethingElse( ); // works because it's cast to the correct type
```

C# Example:

```
BaseClass b = new DerivedClass( );
b.DoSomethingElse( ); // fails because this method doesn't exist for BaseClass
(b as DerivedClass).DoSomethingElse( ); // works because it's cast to the correct type
```

For your details, you can cast it as another type and assign it to a different local variable so as to have the same *instance* viewed as two different types. So you could have a pointer (of type BaseClass) to your object and another pointer (of type DerivedClass) to your object. That is perfectly valid. Consider:

C++:

```
BaseClass* b;
DerivedClass* c;
b = c = new DerivedClass( );
c->DoSomethingElse( ); // totally works
```

C#:

```
BaseClass b;
DerivedClass c;
b = c = new DerivedClass( );
c.DoSomethingElse( ); // totally works
```

[EDIT]: If you're using C++/CLI, just replace the asterisk (*) with a hat (^).